# API call function with completion handler crashes when accessed from different VC

Tags: ios, json, swift, completionhandler

Can someone fix my function code because I have created a API call function which will get the imageURL for the specific object in my class and display the results in the second view controller. I have created custom completion handler so that the code from second VC is only executed when dowloading of the imageURL is completed.

However, when I am testing this function in the second view controller to print me data that it has arrived I am getting a crash on the print statement line.

Here is the code for my API call function located in Model class file:

```
func parseImageData(finished: () -> Void) {

    let urlPath = _exerciseURL
    let url = URL(string: urlPath!)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("Error while parsing JSON")
        }
        else {

            do {
                if let data = data,
                    let fetchedImageData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves) as? [String:Any],
                    let images = fetchedImageData["results"] as? [[String: Any]] {


                    for eachImage in images {
                        let imageUrl = eachImage["image"] as! String
                        self._imageUrl = URL(string: imageUrl)
                    }

                    print(self._imageUrl)


                }
            }
            catch {
                print("Error while parsing data.")
            }
        }

    }
    task.resume()
    finished()
}
```

And here in the second view controller I am just testing if I can access the code block:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    exercise.parseImageData() {
        print("Arrived Here?") // I am getting crash on this line moving to debug navigator.

    }

}
```

Comment: please set completion handler finished()  (before OR after) print(self._imageUrl) and let me know if its work or not ?

Comment: what crash says?

Comment: Are you performing any UI update inside `parseImageData ` completion handler ?

Comment: apparently moving finished() before print statement forced me to change function parameter to @escaping but it works and it now can access the code block in second VC. I still don't understand how because it seems to indicate completion in the middle of the task, but thank you for help.

Comment: In your code `finished()` is called after the code executes, not after the response came. That is why moving it inside the closure worked. Part after `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) ` in curly brackets is executed after your receive response/error

Comment: @Rvfvl , happy to know that one of my suggestion helped you. Happy coding.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the crash says something about `force unwrapping nil` then it's probably because `let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!)` is unwrapping `url` which is a `nil` optional variable here.

But your completion handler is called in the wrong place anyway, try putting your `finished()` callback into the `do` statement instead. Because `finished` was executed the moment you called `exercise.parseImageData()`

```
if error != nil {
   print("Error while parsing JSON")
}
else {

    do {
        if let data = data,
            let fetchedImageData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves) as? [String:Any],
            let images = fetchedImageData["results"] as? [[String: Any]] {


            for eachImage in images {
                let imageUrl = eachImage["image"] as! String
                self._imageUrl = URL(string: imageUrl)
            }

            print(self._imageUrl)

            finished()
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("Error while parsing data.")
    }
}
```

Comment: I moved it and it started to work, but I have no idea why it takes around 10 seconds for image to be updated in the view controller.

Comment: You need to dispatch the image view update onto the main queue.